# Does using set.seed with Sparklyr work now?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

The last time I played with Sparklyr (October '17) there was an issue with using set.seed while working with Sparklyr. I'm not sure what the exact issue was and I can't seem to find anything about it anywhere. Is set.seed working properly with Sparklyr now or is it still an outstanding issue?

Comment: Set seed is for reproducability. It's used in predictive modeling. If I remember right, even when I'm using Scala, I still set the seed. In data science, set seed usually sits at the top of any script that creates a model. It's my expectation that sparklyr works the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In general**

`set.seed` works just fine, where it suppose to - in the local R session a.k.a driver (the place where you call `spark_connect`).

It doesn't work and it cannot work across executors for a number of reasons, including different execution contexts (R, JVM) and / or different environments (with methods like `spark_apply`).

**With Spark wrappers**:

With methods like `ml_*` or `ft_` etc. seed is set by Spark and typically exposed using `seed` argument. For example `ml_kmeans`:

```
> ml_kmeans
function (x, formula = NULL, k = 2L, max_iter = 20L, tol = 1e-04, 
    init_steps = 2L, init_mode = "k-means||", seed = NULL, features_col = "features", 
    prediction_col = "prediction", uid = random_string("kmeans_"), 
    ...) 
{
    UseMethod("ml_kmeans")
}
<environment: namespace:sparklyr>
```

Seed can be also set for RNG SQL functions:

```
> df %>% mutate(rand = rand(42L), randn = randn(42L)) %>% head(3)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
     id  rand  randn
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 0.666  0.409
2     2 0.858  0.881
3     3 0.914 -2.01 
> df %>% mutate(rand = rand(42L), randn = randn(42L)) %>% head(3)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
     id  rand  randn
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 0.666  0.409
2     2 0.858  0.881
3     3 0.914 -2.01
```

**With executor-side R code**

As far as I know there is no option available as of today. Correctly setting RNG seed across multiple machines would require API to access low level task information and even assuming no other sources of non-determinism, can be brittle in heterogeneous environments.

**However**

RNG state is not the only source of nondeterministic behavior in distributed systems. Since in Spark in general doesn't guarantee any specific order of execution, results can different between different runs, even if RNG state is set correctly.

**Overall**:

If your goal is reproducible research you might be still able to use Spark, but it would require a defensive programming, consciously set up cluster, and it is not something you can do with built-in tools, not to mention limited, high level wrappers like `sparklyr`.

Comment: Nice! I'd upvote this more than once if I could. Thanks for the comprehensive answer.